# Strong Induction for Fibonacci number related identity $f_{n+m} = f_{m}f_{n+1} + f_{m-1} f_n$

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

Let $f_n$ be the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number. Let $m$ be a fixed strictly positive integer.

Prove by strong induction that for all $n\ge 0$, 
$$f_{n+m} = f_{m}f_{n+1} + f_{m-1} f_n$$

edit: $f_{n+m} = f_{m}f_{n+1} + f_{m-1} f_n$ instead of $f_{n-m} = f_{m}f_{n+1} + f_{m-1} f_n$
(so sorry lol)

Comment: What if $n=0$ (and of course $m>0$)?

Comment: edit: what i meant is $f_{n+m}$ on the LHS

Comment: I did the basis step for n = 0 and n = 1,and then for the inductive step, I did P(k+1) where P(k) is fn+m=fmfn+1+fm−1. 
Here, LHS(k+1) = $f_{k+m+1}$ and RHS(k+1) = $f_m$ $f_{k+2}$ + $f_{m-1}$ $f_{k+1}$.

Comment: After that, I'm not sure I know how to go from there.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
\begin{align*}
f_{n+1-m} & =f_{n-m}+f_{(n-1)-m}\\
 & =f_{m}f_{n+1}+f_{m-1}f_{n}+f_{m}f_{n}+f_{m-1}f_{n-1}\\
 & =f_{m}(f_{n+1}+f_{n})+f_{m-1}(f_{n}+f_{n-1})\\
 & =\cdots
\end{align*}

Comment: so sorry i screwed up typing the problem.
rather, it's $f_{n+m} = f_{m}f_{n+1} + f_{m-1} f_n$, not $f_{n-m} = f_{m}f_{n+1} + f_{m-1} f_n$